Знаки вопроса вместо русских символов в json файле на python с библиотекой pykwork
При попытке вывести заказы из биржи kwork через api и собирании их в json файл, выводятся пункты titel и description в знаках вопроса, а не в тексте. Код ниже
from kwork import Kwork
import asyncio
import json
import os

async def main():
    api = Kwork(login='pavedolgo@gmail.com', password='Strela1507')
    #profile = await api.get_me()
    #print(profile)

    categories = await api.get_categories()
    
    projects = await api.get_projects(categories_ids=[11])
    print(projects)

    with open('projects.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(projects, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    await api.close()







if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

Компилируется файл json и там вот такой прикол :)


Проверяйте кодировку файлов

Вам нужно разобраться в какой кодировке вы пишете этот json и в какой кодировке потом его смотрите. Скорее всего будет достаточно поменять кодировку, в которой вы json записываете в файл.

я все кодировки перебрал не помогло

Какие пробовали? utf-8, cp1251, cp866, koi8-r?

А пароль то вы зря, кстати, запалили. Меняйте на всякий )

Кстати, в самом API при запросах нельзя кодировку определённую попросить? А то тут скорее всего двойная прекодировка произошла, которая и испортила текст.
